# How to set the criteria parameter in the retrieve method for RemoteObjectController?

Tags: apex, visualforce, salesforcedx, remote-objects

My question is:
How do set the criteria like 'where' and 'orderby' (in the java script below) in the retrieve method for `RemoteObjectController`?

> [**RemoteObjectController**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_system_remoteobjectcontroller.htm)
>   Use RemoteObjectController to access the standard Visualforce Remote Objects operations in your Remote Objects
>   override methods.
>
> **RemoteObjectController Methods**
>    The following are methods for RemoteObjectController. All methods are static.
>
> - create(type, fields)
>     Create a record in the database.
> - del(type, recordIds) Delete records
>     from the database.
> - **retrieve(type, fields, criteria) Retrieve records from the database.**
> - updat(type, recordIds, fields) Update records in the
>     database.
>
> *retrieve(type, fields, criteria)*
>    Retrieve records from the database.
>
> > **Signature** public static Map retrieve(String type, List fields, Map criteria)
> >       **Parameters** type Type: String The sObject type on which retrieve is being called. fields Type: List The fields to retrieve for
> >     each record. criteria Type: Map The criteria to use
> >     when performing the query.

```
<apex:remoteObjectsjsNamespace="RemoteObjectModel">    
    <apex:remoteObjectModel name="Contact" fields="FirstName,LastName"/>  
</apex:remoteObjects>
<script>
var ct = new RemoteObjectModel.Contact();
ct.retrieve( 
    { where: { 
        FirstName: {eq: 'Marc'}, 
        LastName: {eq: 'Benioff'} 
      }, 
      orderby: [ {LastName: 'ASC'}, {FirstName: 'ASC'} ],
      limit: 1 },  
    function(err, records) { 
        if (err) { 
            alert(err); 
        } else { 
            console.log(records.length); 
            console.log(records[0]); 
        } 
    } 
);
</script>

public class TestRemoteActionOverrideController{
    @RemoteAction
    public static Map<String,Object> retrieve(String type, List<String> fields, Map<String, Object> criteria) {
        fields.add('Name');

        //
        // place holder for converting criteria below in java script to apex
        //
        // { where: { 
        // FirstName: {eq: 'Marc'}, 
        // LastName: {eq: 'Benioff'} 
        // }, 
        // orderby: [ {LastName: 'ASC'}, {FirstName: 'ASC'} ],
        // limit: 1 }

        // call through to the default remote object controller with our modified field list.
        return RemoteObjectController.retrieve(type, fields, criteria);
    }
}
```

Comment: I share your question! ... Can developers override the 'WHERE' clause in RemoteObjectController.retrieve ? We can override Fields. We can also override LIMIT clause like so: Map<String, Object> criteriaToOverride = new Map<String, Object>(criteria); criteriaToOverride.put('limit',3); However the WHERE clause in the 'criteria' param seems to be more complex in structure than the Fields/Limit params. My attempts to override criteria give me gack errors despite debugs showing valid-looking criteria & Im not sure if Im overriding the Map<String,Object> criteria correctly.

Comment: not sure if the retrieve="{!$RemoteAction.TestRemoteActionOverrideController.retrieve}" is required as an attribute in apex:remoteObjectModel, but yeah modifying "where" clause gives the error like collection is read only, and again gives the error even if you clone the criteria!

Comment: I was able to genereate the Map<String,Object> criteria with JSON.deserializeUntyped by following the instructions in the link below...
https://opfocus.com/json-deserialization-techniques-in-salesforce/

Unfortunately, my TestRemoteActionOverrideController did not work, it received a Salesforce system error.
Error: Salesforce System Error: 1732853427-40796 (-939844238) (-939844238)

If someone has a working example of the retrieve method override for RemoteObjectController, please post it here.

Comment: Hmm, similar fate here; I too get a Visualforce Remoting Exception: Salesforce System Error: 843950615-35463 (1954984097) (1954984097).  If anyone has a working example of overriding the query "criteria" in  System.RemoteObjectController.retrieve and can show that it works in their visualforce page's apex:remoteObjectModel  then please share.